# SpringDoc/Swagger doc not displaying correct url

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-ui

I have setup a base context-path for my spring boot 3 application and I am using spring-doc to display documentation in a swagger-ui. However, when deployed my apps url path gets prefixed with `/service-api`. This causes a problem when trying to view my swagger-ui documentation in the browser because it cant load the swagger.json for the ui. I can override the url with `springdoc.swagger-ui.url: /service-api/api/service/swagger.json`. However, I get this url when I load the swagger ui from my browser:
`/api/service/service-api/api/service/swagger.json`. But, I need it display: `/service-api/api/service/swagger.json`. I think the context-path is getting appended by default to the path I have setup in my application.yaml. Is there a way to disable context-path from getting appended in the swagger-ui?

Here is my applications.yaml

```
# Server
server:
  port: 9000
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/service
    application-display-name: service-api

# Spring Doc
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
    url: /service-api/api/service/swagger.json
  api-docs:
    path: /swagger.json
```

Here are my dependancies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I have also tried setting with `springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl`. But, I just get an empty url in the swagger ui when using configUrl.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your application.yaml file

```
spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

use io.springfox librabry instead of io.swagger.core.v3 you can get it from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2/3.0.0

Comment: Spring Boot 3 does not support springfox anymore. It is recommended to use spring docs openapi 3